# Compare columns values iteratively in the same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare, bioinformatics

My ultimate goal is to getting rid of the genes, which are overlapping. In order to do that I determined three conditions but I am not going into detail about them. If you need those to provide an alternative approach, I can mention them.

Basically, I want to compare two columns' values (int64). However, I want to do it such a way that a single row should be compared with all the remaining rows and if the conditions are satisfied, the same steps should be performed for the next and other rows, sequentially.

I need every row in the dataframe to be checked whether the given condition satisfied or not. During this process, I need to use the two columns' ("Start" and "End") values. You can see one of the condition in my pseudocode below.

If the below condition satisfied, I want to either drop the row (DF2.loc[row_loop]) or create a new column and assign a label which enable me to understand wheter there is an overlap or not. Then, I can remove those rows.

Condition:

(rowA ["Start"] >= rowB ["Start"]) and (rowA ["Start"] <= rowB ["End"]) and (rowA ["End"] >= rowB ["Start"]) and (rowA ["End"] >= rowB ["End"])

That is what my dataframe looks like:

```
DF2.head()
```

|  | Chromosome_Name | Sequence_Source | Sequence_Feature | Start | End | Strand | Gene_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | ensembl_havana | gene | 14363 | 34806 | - | "ENSG00000227232" |
| 1 | 1 | havana | gene | 89295 | 138566 | - | "ENSG00000238009" |
| 2 | 1 | havana | gene | 141474 | 178862 | - | "ENSG00000241860" |
| 3 | 1 | havana | gene | 227615 | 272253 | - | "ENSG00000228463" |
| 4 | 1 | ensembl_havana | gene | 312720 | 453948 | + | "ENSG00000237094" |

That's what I have so far:

```
for ref_row in range(0, len(DF2) - 1):
   for row_loop in range(ref_row + 1, len(DF2)):
     if (DF2.loc[ref_row, ["Start"]] >= DF2.loc[row_loop, ["Start"]]) & (DF2.loc[ref_row, ["Start"]] <= DF2.loc[row_loop, ["End"]]) & (DF2.loc[ref_row, ["End"]] >=  DF2.loc[row_loop, ["Start"]]) & (DF2.loc[ref_row, ["End"]] >= DF2.loc[row_loop, ["End"]]):
        DF2.drop(row_loop)
```

After running the above code, I got an ValueError which says "Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects."

I also replaced the if condition with the:

```
DF2["Overlap"] = np.where((DF2.loc[ref_row, ["Start"]] >= DF2.loc[row_loop, ["Start"]]) & (DF2.loc[ref_row, ["Start"]] <= DF2.loc[row_loop, ["End"]]) & (DF2.loc[ref_row, ["End"]] >=  DF2.loc[row_loop, ["Start"]]) & (DF2.loc[ref_row, ["End"]] >= DF2.loc[row_loop, ["End"]]), np.nan, DF2["Gene_Name"])
```

but still getting the same ValueError.

Can anyone provide me the solution or maybe another approach for reaching my objective?

Thanks in advance.

Btw, I am sorry for my English. I had a hard time to explain my aim by writing, I hope you got it.

Comment: In your first conditional, you reference `DF` variable. Is this a mistake? All other conditionals reference `DF2`, and you never talk about a `DF` variable.

Comment: Careful with dropping rows while iterating over them. You'll encounter indexing errors. Your second attempted solution where you create an overlap boolean column is a better solution.

Comment: Yes, my bad. I've corrected the variable name. Thanks for showing me my mistake. I am still working on finding an answer for my problem. I realized that, in fact, iterating and comparing the same row all over the data is causing the removal of extra rows from the dataframe. I think before iterating the rows, first, I need to group the dataframe according to the chromosome names (starting from 1 to 23) then, I should iterate and compare the rows within each group, not with the rows belong to other chromosome groups.

Comment: Btw, I do not understand one think in the code. When you say `DF2["Overlap"] = False` doesn't it create a column with values of False? So, I do not understand that how this (`if DF2.loc[ref_row]["Overlap"] != False:`) line of the code will work? Since, all the row values are False and how can I expect to see a row which is not False? Your code is probably very straightforward but I am kind a newbie in the programming languages so apologize for my weird question in advance.

Comment: you are correct. `DF2["Overlap"] = False` creates a row of all false values. But the conditional `if DF2.loc[ref_row]["Overlap"] != False` applies only to the row `DF2.loc[ref_row]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your demo data and code:

Build test dataframe (this should be included in future questions)

```
DF2 = {
'Chromosome_Name': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
'Sequence_Source': ['ensembl_havana', 'havana', 'havana', 'havana', 'ensembl_havana'], 
'Sequence_Feature': ['gene', 'gene', 'gene', 'gene', 'gene'], 
'Start': [14363, 89295, 141474, 227615, 312720], 
'End': [34806, 138566, 178862, 272253, 453948], 
'Strand': ['-', '-', '-', '-', '+'],
'Gene_ID': ['ENSG00000227232', 'ENSG00000238009', 'ENSG00000241860', 'ENSG00000228463', 'ENSG00000237094']
}
```

Designate rows that overlap

```
DF2["Overlap"] = False # create column to track overlap
for ref_row in range(0, len(DF2)-1):
    for row_loop in range(ref_row+1, len(DF2)):
        # update overlap to true, does not allow revert to False
        if DF2.loc[ref_row]["Overlap"] != False:
            DF2[ref_row]["Overlap"] = np.where(
                (DF2.loc[ref_row]["Start"] >= DF2.loc[row_loop]["Start"]) & \
                (DF2.loc[ref_row]["Start"] <= DF2.loc[row_loop]["End"]) & \
                (DF2.loc[ref_row]["End"] >=  DF2.loc[row_loop]["Start"]) & \
                (DF2.loc[ref_row]["End"] >= DF2.loc[row_l]["End"])
            )
```

I removed `np.nan` and `DF2["Gene_Name"]` from the conditional to simplify. With the current conditional, no overlap was found. You'll probably want to break up the conditional into two parts:

1. is A inside B?
2. is B inside A?

The error you encountered was due to improper use of `.loc`.

```
DF2.loc[2, ["Start"]]
Out: 
Start    141474
Name: 2, dtype: object

DF2.loc[2]["Start"]
Out: 141474
```